# Cancelable Forward

Tags: option-pricing, fx, forward-rate

How I could modeling a break forward or cancelable forward? Could I use Swaption model or only by montecarlo simulation?

I have (X-F) for 2Y but I have option to cancel in 0,5Y by a premium price

Comment: Is it cancellable by one or both parties, and at what level is it cancelled?

Comment: Only one partie, this contract is cancel if (X-F +Premium )<0 at option expire and pay Premium by do it.

Comment: It sounds like it's just an option then. Price it using black.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, NDF(Time=2y) + black option(time=0,25y). However, when I try to compare with montecarlo simulation, I got a different result. When I use the same time, both 2y or 0,25 y my montecarlo is equal  NDF + black76 opption, however when I change time expiration, alwalys I have different values.